# All images are not downloaded when using Glide with RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

This problem I have faced a lot when using `Glide` (v3.8.0) to load list of images in a `RecyclerView`.

1. I am trying to load 9 images **(jpg format and 1000 x 1000 size)** from server. `Glide` downloads few images and show it. But some are not downloaded and I have to re-open the `Activity` to download the remaining images.
2. As **`Glide`** download images. The **`Activity`** gets slower and slower. The scrolling is very laggy.

Here is the `onBindViewHolder` of the `RecyclerView`.

```
RequestManager manager;
Context context;
List<Gallery> galleryList;

public BaseAdapter(Context context, List<Gallery> galleryList, RequestManager glide) {
    this.context = context;
    this.galleryList = galleryList;
    this.manager = glide;
}

@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(final KolamViewHolder holder, final int itemPosition) {
    Log.e("BaseAdapter", galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage());
    manager.load(galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage()).asBitmap()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    holder.kolamImage.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.e("BaseAdapter", "Ready");
                    //click listener to pass the gallery image to the bot
                    holder.kolamImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(galleryList.get(itemPosition));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Where am I making a mistake? How can I load all the images and without making any lag while scrolling?

Comment: Download the small resolution of Images and once the user clicks on them get a 1000*1000 dimension image. So you need to store 2 variant of images on your server!

Comment: @Hiren Y you are loading all images as Bitmap ? Are you performing any operation on it ?

Comment: @androidnoobdev just to display it in ImageView. I am using listener which by default uses `GlideDrawable` but I want `Bitmap` to be returned in the listener.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a chance of garbage collecting the SimpleTarget object. So sometimes your image won't be set in the image view. In order to solve this, you should set the target image view using into() method of builder class and put a placeholder for showing loading by placeholder() method.And implement onclick() on the image view.

Comment: I am getting `timeout` error if I am using @androidnoobdev answer. But with my implementation I am able to download at least 6 images.

Comment: So you can use my logic. This will work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple load images from URL using Glide without creating bitmap for all. I think that process is unnecessary for you.

```
Glide.with(context).load(galleryList.get(itemPosition).getImage())
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
.dontAnimate()
.override(150,150) // Customize size as per requirement
.placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.mipmap.ic_user_placeholder_50dp))
.listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
    @Override public boolean onException(Exception e, String model,
        Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model,
        Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache,
        boolean isFirstResource) {
        return false;
    }
})
.into(holder.kolamImage);
```

Hope it will help...

Comment: I want to use `listener` with that. Please show me the listener implementation with your answer.

Comment: its throwing exception :(. Its not entering `onResourceReady()`
Getting this error:
`SSL handshake timeout`

Comment: For that you can check this - https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/432

Comment: This way of implementation is giving `timeout` error only.

Comment: I am getting `timeout` error. But with my implementation I am able to download at least 6 images. But with your implementation I am getting only timeout error.